# undefined reference to `for_simd_random_number'

Tags: linux, fortran, undefined-reference

recently when I tried to compile a fortran code using intel compiler version 11.1.073 on Linux, I ran into the following error:

```
>>> BUILDING: PaSR
make[1]: Entering directory `/autofs/na3_home1/xl/ISAT_V11/PaSR'
ftn -O2 -fPIC -I../isatab_ser -I../isat-ck -I../ice-pic -c pasr.f
ftn -O2 -fPIC -I../isatab_ser -I../isat-ck -I../ice-pic -c pasrsubs.f
ftn -O2 -fPIC -I../isatab_ser -I../isat-ck -I../ice-pic -c usrate.f
ftn -o PaSR pasr.o pasrsubs.o usrate.o -Bstatic -L/ccs/home/xl/ISAT_V11/lib 
-lisat7_ser -lck_ext -llapack -Bstatic
/ccs/home/xl/ISAT_V11/lib/libisat7_ser.a(ci_ice_pic_bound.o): In 
function `ci_ice_pic_bound_test_':
ci_ice_pic_bound.f90:(.text+0x34f): undefined reference to `for_simd_random_number'
/usr/bin/ld: link errors found, deleting executable `PaSR'
make[1]: *** [PaSR] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/autofs/na3_home1/xl/ISAT_V11/PaSR'
make: *** [build-programs] Error 1
```

It seems to me that the code cannot find a specific lib (in intel shared libs) which it needs and thus causing the error. I have successfully used intel/13.1.3.192 to compile it. But not with intel/11.1.073. I have searched the web for 'for_simd_random_number' but didn't find a clue.

Please do offer your wisdom. I appreciate it!

Comment: Are you sure it is intel? Did you set the environment?

Comment: Yep, I load the PrgEnv-intel and also use the intel/11.1.073.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol `for_simd_random_number` is defined in the library `ifcore` in intel fortran 13. However it is not present in your intel fortran 11 libraries, so you cannot link agains it.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I tried to add -lifcore to my linker flags in the Makefile as follows (correct me if I am wrong): LDFLAGS= -L$(LIBS_PATH) -lisat7_ser -lck_ext $(MKL_LIST) -lifcore    And it still gave me the same error:  ftn -o PaSR pasr.o pasrsubs.o usrate.o -Bstatic -L/ccs/home/xl/ISAT_V11/lib -lisat7_ser -lck_ext -llapack -lifcore -Bstatic
/ccs/home/xl/ISAT_V11/lib/libisat7_ser.a(ci_ice_pic_bound.o): In function `ci_ice_pic_bound_test_':
ci_ice_pic_bound.f90:(.text+0x34f): undefined reference to `for_simd_random_number'

Comment: Its either linker [order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc) or the symbol is really not there? (what gives you nm libifcore.so.X | grep "for_simd_random_number" for your intel 11 installation)

Comment: /opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/073/lib/intel64> nm libifcore.so.5 | grep "for_simd_random_number"  I tried this but it gave me nothing :(

Comment: However, if I do this in a latest intel compiler version, it'll give me the following: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/compiler/lib/intel64> nm libifcore.so.5 | grep "for_simd_random_number"
0000000000088030 T for_simd_random_number
0000000000088700 T for_simd_random_number_avx
0000000000088850 T for_simd_random_number_avx_mask
00000000000881a0 T for_simd_random_number_mask
0000000000088320 T for_simd_random_number_single
00000000000889a0 T for_simd_random_number_single_avx
0000000000088bb0 T for_simd_random_number_single_avx_mask
0000000000088510 T for_simd_random_number_single_mask

Comment: `grep -r "for_simd_random_number" .`  in your intel 11 lib installation?

Comment: /opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/073/lib/intel64> grep -r "for_simd_random_number" .    and it gave me nothing, either :(

Comment: but if I do this in latest version, it gave me the following: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/compiler/lib/intel64> grep -r "for_simd_random_number" .
Binary file ./libifcore.a matches
Binary file ./libifcore.so.5 matches
Binary file ./libifcoremt.so.5 matches
Binary file ./libifcore_pic.a matches
Binary file ./libifcoremt.a matches
Binary file ./libifcoremt_pic.a matches

Comment: Maybe someone else can give you more details when it has been introduced and what are possible alternatives.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it gives you what you wanted

Comment: I dont have 15 reputation to vote this answer up but I do make it green. Is it the right way to accept the answer?

Comment: You are linking to objects or libraries compiled with a newer Intel Fortran that uses that symbol. Recompile ALL your Fortran sources.

Comment: Yes, Steve. I recompiled everything and then there is no such problem.